# Relating one item in a relational database with one or more others

Tags: sql, database

I have a list of items to be stored in a database.  Each item can be associated with one or more predetermined categories.  The list of categories may grow over time.  What is the best way to associate one item with one or more categories (objects)?  I thought about serialising the list and putting it into a single cell but this seems against the whole idea of a relational database.

Functionality I may require could be Filtering a list of items by their category and finding all items belonging to a category.

So responding to comments I will try to be more clear my apologies.

So how about a quick example:

Say you have a list of foods each of which can be classified into a different category.  You could have a simple table

```
    food_name |  category 

    Apple |  sweet  
    Chicken | Cooked food
```

What should you then do if you want to classify a food under two categories?

```
    Apple |   sweet   
    Chicken | Cooked food   
    Apple pie |   cooked food, sweet   
    biscuit cracker |   salty, snack food
```

This I thought would not be a good approach as it involves another step of encoding and decoding.  So I was wondering if there was a better way to basically get around storing a list of data in a single cell of a table?

PS apologies I use a screen reader so hope you understand the table I am trying to make.

Comment: maybe look at a tutorial of the very basics of relational databases. it should cover that

Comment: @x4rf41 ok thanks for the suggestion - I have tried to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tagging system.  In it's simplest incarnation it uses three tables.  In your case they would be `Foods`, `Categories`, and `FoodCategories`.

`Food` contains the column `FoodID` or `FoodName` as a `PRIMARY KEY`.  That value *uniquely* identifies each record.  It can also contain any other columns that pertain to that food (and only that food).

`Categories` contains the column `Category` as `PRIMARY KEY`.  It can also contain descriptive columns about the category.

Finally, `FoodCategories` contains exactly two columns, `FoodID` and `Category`.  `FoodID` is a `FOREIGN KEY` to the table `Foods` and `Category` is a `FOREIGN KEY` to the table `Categories`.  The two columns *together* (`FoodID, Category`) are the `PRIMARY KEY` for this table.

To "add" a food to a category, you `INSERT` a record into the `FoodCategories` table.  To add the same food to another category you `INSERT` *another* record in this table.  To remove a food from a category, you `DELETE` the appropriate record.

Comment: Thanks this sounds good.  Can I ask: so how efficient is it then to actually retrieve all foods under a single category for example?  or vice versa?  Will it have an n complexity (as in will it have to traverse the entire table as they are not unique keys within the table).  Or is the fact that they are foreign keys speed up the table allowing some kind of indexing?

Comment: In the exact set-up I listed, searches of `FoodCategories` by `Category` will not use an index.  You could either make the `PRIMARY KEY` on this table (`Category, FoodID`) instead (but that will make `FoodID` searches not-indexed) or else add an additional `INDEX` on `Category` in that table.